# IF statement needed to display text at certain width and only on the home page

Tags: php, css, wordpress

I was wondering if there was an if statement I could use that would a.) only show some text on the front page of the website (which I have achieved) but also b.) only display this text up to a certain width (1126px).

Here's what I got so far, inside my header.php ...

```
<div class="contact-details">

<?php if ( is_front_page() ) {
            echo '020 1234 1234 <span>|</span> <a href="">test</a>';
}

?>

</div>
```

Note: this is a WordPress website.

Comment: PHP has no clue of any “screen width”. You already tagged this with `media-queries`, so you seem to be already aware what the proper tool to solve this is. So, what is your actual question then …?

Comment: Just use a CSS class if you need to display the text for a certain resolution, look at media queries. `@media screen and (max-width: 1126px)` ..

Comment: Address the scope of the width with standard media queries and responsive design techniques. Your conditional check should work for static home pages.

Comment: @CBroe I thought it might be a combination of media-queries and PHP. Tagged media-queries to attract the people I thought would be best to answer the question.. along with a PHP tag too.

Comment: @VincentDecaux Okay, so I set up a media query to display none at the max-width. However, this removes it from the home page also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorted this out now :) - Removed the PHP if statement and just used CSS.

```
.contact-details {
display: block; /* other styles were above this line */
}

body.home .contact-details {
    display: block;
}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {
    .contact-details {
        display: none;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use JS to hide the element if it is bigger than the given size:

```
if($(".contact-details").width() > 1126) {
  $(".contact-details").hide();
}
```